# Смена языка на сайте по нажатию на toggle

Tags: javascript, php, html

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать смену языка на сайте через toggle? Имеется скрипт PHP:

**СЛОВАРЬ:**

```html
<?php 
class LangDicts {
  public static $rus = array('News' => 'Новости');
  public static $eng = array('News' => 'News');
  public static $dict; // текущий словарь
    
}
  
?>
```

**РУЧНАЯ СМЕНА ЯЗЫКА:**

```html
      <? 
require \filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/include/lang.php';

LangDicts::$dict = LangDicts::$rus; ?>
```

**САМ TOGGLE:**

```html
                     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <span class="text-white">RU</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="switch" /><label for="switch"></label>
                        <span class="text-white">EN</span>
                     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выбранный язык надо где-то хранить (состояние) -- в URL, в cookie, в сессии на сервере -- по обстановке.

Соответственно toggle должен по клику это состояние менять,
а view (который хтмл делает) -- состояние читать и класть в $dict, что нужно.